# Symfony 4 Cannot access to mappedEntity in twig

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

I have two model, Bodyshops and BodyshopsSchedule

I bound with each other with a manyToMany relationship like that

**Entity/Bodyshops.php**

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\BodyshopsSchedule", inversedBy="bodyshops")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="join_bodyshops_bodyshopsSchedule")
 */
private $schedules;
```

**Entitiy/BodyshopsSchedule**

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Bodyshops", mappedBy="schedules")
 */
private $bodyshops;
```

I created an Add, Get and Set function in each file for each values

I bound them together and in phpMyAdmin I can see in the joinTable that everything is nice !

**But when I try to print an attribute of BodyshopsSchedule cross Bodyshops class it doesn't work and i got an error**

*Key "0" in object with ArrayAccess of class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" does not exist.*

from

```
<h5 id="{{bodyshop.id ~ '_city'}}" class="card-text"> {{ bodyshop.schedules[0].day }} </h5>
```

**I tried to use {{ bodyshop.schedules.day|first }}**

*Neither the property "day" nor one of the methods "day()", "getday()"/"isday()"/"hasday()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection".*

**To Iter with in a for**

*Key "" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21" does not exist.*

But I always get an error

I wanna know how to get a BodyshopsSchedule instead of a PersistentCollection.

Thank's for reading ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
{{ bodyshop.schedules.first.day }}
```

Since the `schedules` is an object of class implementing the [Collection interface](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.Collection.html), you can use [its methods](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/source-class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.Collection.html#141-147) in Twig. You should also read how to [handle collections](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html) in Twig.

Comment: I already tried too and i get a "Impossible to access an attribute ("day") on a boolean variable ("")." I thought that it was an error like the others but no ! It's the good way, I guess that I got that because my day is a varchar(1) do you know how can i correct it ?

Comment: And I did a For bodyshop in bodyshops follow by a For schedule in bodyshop.schedule when i got the "Key "" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21" does not exist." this is why i think that i have an index problem too

Comment: I can also use {{ bodyshop.schedules.get(0).day }} ! but the parameter that i try to get is maybe null, and {% if bodyshop.schedules is defined %} doesn't correct anything :(

Comment: {{ bodyshop.schedules.get(0).Value|default('undefined') }} worked ! thank's for your help !

Comment: Read the contract first (interface details). It says that the first method returns Boolean false if an element was not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set  `strict_variables: false`in the twig config